# Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:installDebug'

Tags: java, android, react-native, android-studio

I'm new to react-native.
I set up my android studio and emulator working fine when starting it from avd manager. However when i run **react-native run-android** i get this error:

```
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:installDebug'.
> java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
```

Is there anything missing? what should i do?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you please state the directory name of your workspace? Any special characters etc?

Comment: @Satheeshwaran C:\Users\Ahmadbenos\dev tests\shopping-list\testShop

Comment: Remove the space between 'dev tests' it can be 'dev-tests' and try once.

Comment: @AhmadBenos clear npm-modules folder and re install it

Comment: @Satheeshwaran didn't work

Comment: @HendEl-Sahli did not work, i think there's a problem in the gradle stuff.

Comment: @AhmadBenos Then try to open your project in `android studio` and it will be clear if it's gradle issue after syncing...